# Jquery Not working to create new Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my Html Doc and the JQuery does not do anything when the range input changes, any assistance is much appreciated as I am extremely new to web design. Even the alert doesn't work at the top so I am unsure as to what my problem is. My belief is somehow the script is never being called or it's a problem with it being an html doc but either way thank you.

```
     <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var num=0;
        var numOptions = new Array(100);
        window.onload = function() {
            if (window.jQuery) {  
                // jQuery is loaded  
                alert("Yeah!");
            } else {
                // jQuery is not loaded
                alert("Doesn't Work");
            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#numQuestions").on('input',function(){
            var numbQuestions = $("#numQuestions".text());
            if(num>numbQuestions){
                for(i=numbQuestions;i<=num;i++){
                    try{
                        $("#qRowNum'+i).remove();
                        }catch(err){

                        }
                    }
                    }else{
                    for ( i=num;  i < numbQuestions;  i++) 
                    { 
                        var row = '<div id="qRowNum'+ i '">   

#the below function is not implemented in this version 
<input type="text" placeholder="Question '+i'">    <input type="range" name="numOptions'+i'" min="0" max="5" placeholder="Number Of Options" onchange="CreateOptions(this);" onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();> </div>';
                        $("#questionRows").append(row);
                        //New script test


                    }
                }
                num = numbQuestions;
            });
        });
                           <div id="questionRows">

            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Start">
        </form>

            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Use JSLint or somehow sort out all the syntax errors

Comment: `$("#numQuestions").on(` will never fire that event as that element does not exist at the time this executes.

Comment: You never close your script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
var numbQuestions = $("#numQuestions".text());
```

Firstly I think you mean this:

```
var numbQuestions = $("#numQuestions").text();
```

But that is also not true because an `input` field has not `text` property. They have `value` So do this:

```
var numbQuestions = $("#numQuestions").val();
```

And this is another problem: `$("#qRowNum'+i)`  When you start selector by double quotation, you need to end this also by double quotation. But it still is not a true jquery selector.

I think you need to more studies about jquery.